# Reference for Dedekind's problem

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, boolean-algebras

[Dedekind's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind's_problem) is about enumerating antichains in the Boolean lattice. 
Is there an explicit reference where Dedekind stated this problem?
Is there a good motivation to study this problem except that it is an old open problem stated by a famous mathematician?

Comment: I don't know an exact reference (probably OEIS may provide some). However, for motivation, I can say that I struggled with some computations that have this problem as a particular case. For example, see here https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.00864 an article on which Bruns, Garcia and Moci try to compute the number of irreducible elements on the monoid Q(M) when M is a uniform matroid (I can't add the details here, but if M is the uniform matroid with rank n and n elements, this number reduces to Dedekind's problem). Being able to compute them would be very interesting.

Comment: Richard Dedekind, [Über Zerlegungen von Zahlen durch ihre größten gemeinsamen Teiler](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-663-07224-9_1), Gesammelte Werke, 2, pp. 103–148 (1897). _regrettably behind a paywall_

Answer (score 2):

Speaking as a nonexpert, the enumeration and classification of monotone Boolean functions can give insight into optimization problems in logic, for instance by considering how far off an arbitrary function is from a monotone one.  Doing a web search should reveal other motivations for studying Dedekind's problem.

Gerhard "Who Doesn't Like Enumeration Problems?" Paseman, 2020.02.12.